# Inserting data in many to many relation ship in EF core

Tags: .net, entity

i have two tables

1-Employees (ID ,EmpName)

2- Project (ID,ProjectName)

data is already inserted in boh tables ,there is many to many relationship between these two so middle table created in table i.e EmployeesProject

now i want to insert data (keys of both table i.e EmpID,ProjectID ) in Midddle in order to maintain Many to many relationship,can some one help me how to do this .. please not down i m using EFcore .

create classes for both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeProject> EmployeeProjects { get; set; }
}
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeProject> EmployeeProjects { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeProject
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).